# poetry: How to ignore beta version and install latest alpha version?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-poetry

I've a package registry for my package `framework`. I want to get the latest **alpha** version from the package registry while there are **beta** versions available for same release. Example

```
Registry:
  - framework 0.0.1a0
  - framework 0.0.1a1
  - framework 0.0.1b0
  - framework 0.0.1b1
```

My pypoetry.toml file

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
framework = {version = "^0.0.1", allow-prerelease = true}
```

I want to install `framework` latest alpha version (0.0.1a1) while this configuration installs (0.0.1b1).

Answer (score 1):

Install package of a specified version by adding a version variable and an "allow pre-releases" tag (`--allow-prereleases`) if its a pre-release package in your poetry add command.

For example:

```
                                 Specify the package version here
                                          vvvvvvvvvvv
poetry add --allow-prereleases bit-vector="^0.42.0a0"
                               ^^^^^^^^^^
                      Replace it with the package name
```

[`GitHub link to the exact issue`](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/824)

Comment: Thank you, but I need to keep updating this every time new alpha package is released. I need a permanent solution

Comment: I believe you can use wild card syntax to specify the alpha package versions, so it'll find a matching version when doing poetry update. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54720072/dependency-version-syntax-for-python-poetry

Comment: I did it with wild card too `0.0.1a*`, but didn't worked out. Is this right?

Comment: It looks like there's something right and something wrong in your version var but I cant get what feels wrong. Try something like `0.0.1*`?  https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/3538#issuecomment-843679864